# Prevent OS X Mavericks from autoquitting applications for sleep

Tags: macos, sleep-wake

OS X Mavericks is quitting applications when it 'sleeps' an account.  One of the applications (play on mac) doesn't support this.  Thus Chrome, TextEdit etc. are being quit and then it asks if I want to manually exit PlaysOnMac.  Thus the quit applications I lose what web pages I had opened, what text files I had opened etc. as they are not restored when this happens.

How do I disable this quitting behavior?

Comment: What are you referring to as "sleeping" an account? The only thing I could think of would be fast user switching, which does not quit applications.

Comment: With three different interpretations of what might be causing the app quit - would you edit in some more details on the specifics so we can clean up any false guesses. Hopefully the responses so far will help both you and in editing this so others can use it to help.

Answer (score 1):

Go to System Preferences, choose "Security & Privacy" and click on the locker on the lower left. Insert your password and click on "Advanced" on lower right.
Uncheck "Log out after ... minutes of inactivity"

Answer (score 0):

Actually Mavericks can and will quit and suspend apps without user action so you have to check in Activity Monitor whether the apps being quit support these new features.

Providing a detailed answer will not be possible without knowing:

- exactly what apps you are seeing quit
- what load is on the system when this happens

However, this could be expected behavior if you have apps that informed OSX to control their start and stop based on usage patterns and loading on the system.